# why is this code in the array not suitable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, arrays

im trying to insert : `return confirm('Sei sicuro di voler eliminare? Clicca annulla se non ne sei sicuro.');`

in :

```
        <a href='deleteday.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' >Elimina</a>
```

but i doesnt work....

i tried:

```
<a href='deleteday.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'return confirm(\'Sei sicuro di voler eliminare? Clicca annulla se non ne sei sicuro.\'); >Elimina</a>
```

why??

Comment: Why don't you use it on `onclick="return confirm(\'Sei sicuro di voler eliminare? Clicca annulla se non ne sei sicuro.\');"`?

Comment: Aside from the above comment - you have quoting issues. The syntax highlighting should help you. `href='deleteday.php?id=" . $row['` <-- string ends here.

Comment: Also ONE visit from google bot will wipe your database. NEVER put a delete in a GET/HREF

Answer (score 2):

NEVER put a delete in a href

One visit from a spider could be very bad

Try this

```
<div id="someContainer">
  <a href='#' data-id='<?= $row['id']; ?>' class="delete">Elimina</a>
  <a href='#' data-id='<?= $row['id']; ?>' class="delete">Elimina</a>
  <a href='#' data-id='<?= $row['id']; ?>' class="delete">Elimina</a>
</div>
```

with

```
document.getElementById("someContainer").addEventListener("click",e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("delete") {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    if (confirm('Sei sicuro di voler eliminare? Clicca annulla se non ne sei sicuro.')) {
      location = "deleteday.php?id="+tgt.dataset.id
    }
  }
})
```

It is recommended that you change

```
location = "deleteday.php?id="+tgt.dataset.id
```

to a POST, for example using `fetch`

Comment: All "reading" submissions are cool to use the `$_GET` superglobal.  When "writing` (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) data, it is best practice to use `$_POST`.  A "spider" that becomes aware of urls that trigger deletion will cause trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put it into the below given example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return confirm('hello');"> Click On me!</a>
```